# ystockquote.py urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python

I am using ystockquote.py which is the Yahoo Finance API created by Corey Goldberg. I was importing the module and when I tried doing

```
ystockquote.get_historical_prices('GOOG', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-08')
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ystockquote.py", line 485, in get_historical_prices
    resp = urlopen(req)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

I have no idea what is wrong since I believe the API was created correctly as Goldberg as displayed on github the correct result. The older version of ystockquote.py by Corey Goldberg is also giving the error.

Comment: the error indicates that the URL used to access Yahoo is wrong. You may want to check for a newer version of ystockquote or contact the author.

Comment: This is the error that the file is giving on the newer version. I downloaded the older version and tried it out and that gave me an error as well. On his github, he showed that this functionality was valid so I had no idea of how he was able to do it.

Comment: you may want to consider this fork and notice: https://github.com/GaZ3ll3/ystockquote/commit/e7e1d71f0bc43f46d78a82ebffa0b6960395d83c

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks so much. I need to make sure I notice these details carefully.